# Wiring electric helmet directly to snowmobile battery

Tags: battery, wiring

I have an electric snowmobile helmet with a RCA plug and not instructions. The black wire has a connector for the screw terminal on the battery, but the red wire is bare. What do I connect the red wire to?

[image][image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Generally the red wire would be attached to the power source. It could be connected directly to the positive battery terminal or attached to the fuse box. What ever source you use, it must include a fuse or circuit breaker to prevent an overload and potential fire hazard. We can't see all that is included in the wiring. It is possible that there is a fuse in the wiring that we are unable to see. The black wire can be attached to either the  negative battery terminal or a chassis ground.

Comment: I've added another picture of the wires. No fuse that I can see. The battery does have another adapter coming off it but it isn't RCA. That looks to have a fuse

Comment: Everything *mikes* said was correct. But just a quick note: if possible, avoid connecting the red (+) and black (-) wires directly to the battery terminals. There is nothing "wrong" with doing it this way, but it is a little "sloppy" and not the "proper" way to wire accessories. As mikes said, try to use an existing *accessories* connection on the fuse box for the red (+) wire, and a frame ground for the black (-) wire.

Comment: I've added a picture of the battery that looks to have an accessory adapter and fuse, just not RCA.

Comment: Hmm I see. In the third picture, is that the RCA plug on the left hand side? It looks like there are 2 wires coming out of the RCA plug, right? Those 2 wires should go to the positive and negative battery terminals. There should be a fuse between the positive battery terminal and the RCA plug. Is that correct?

Comment: I added a close up of the accessory plug. It is fused, but taking the cap of it's not RCA (I don't think). It looks like both wires of accessory plug go to red terminal. Wires are very tight. In the background you can see something else with two screws and wires drawing power, I don't know what this is either

Comment: Ah ok, that is a [male bullet connector](https://www.delcity.net/store/Bullet-Connectors/p_801749). They plug into **female bullet connectors**. This type of connector is common in automotive applications. If the connector is currently not used, you can crimp a female bullet connector to your red (+) wire, and connect them. Then screw the black (-) wire to an exposed metal surface on the frame of your snow mobile.

Comment: A word of caution: take care that the unplugged loom portion permanently installed to the battery is free from any possibility of shorting. I bought a second hand Harley that the original owner had wired for a heated rainsuit (*<cough> <cough> sally <cough>*). Long story short, I found myself at a remote scenic outlook unable to get any life in my bike. It wasn't until I simply moved the positive terminal away from an adjacent frame member that everything sprang back to life. Lesson learned.

Comment: Layout for red wires: red (+) battery terminal -> fuse -> male bullet connector -> female bullet connector -> red (+) accessory wire

Comment: It looks like a male and female connector, or it's two prong on the bullet plug. The picture show the male up font. Do I need both or just one? I have two helmets I'd like to plug in but at least get one working for now

Comment: The male/female to female/male connection is designed that way so there is no way for you to get it wrong. If there isn't a dummy rubber or plastic insert attached to the plug by a small plastic strap to cover the battery end then you might want to try and find one to use when it's not in use. [Dielectric grease](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/71517/should-i-remove-dielectric-grease-from-electrical-sockets) would be a good choice, especially for preserving a connection during inclimate weather unless you're planning on leaving the helmet permanently attached to the vehicle.